# Acessing nested data from BehaviorSubject in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, behaviorsubject

For my project I have to get a json file from an api.
This data is then put into an Angular service in order to provide the data to my components.

A codesandbox can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-7khq9

An external API is providing the data. For testing purposes I am including it as a `.json` file here.
The test data is:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "a": 42,
        "b": 43
    }
}
```

I want the components to get the latest data so I am using a `BehaviorSubject` based on [this](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#data-service-ts) article (using the last method), as subscribed components automatically get the newest data.

```
export class DataService {
    private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject({});
    currentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.http
          .get("https://7khq9.codesandbox.io/assets/data.json")
          .subscribe(data => {
               this.changeData(data);
          });
    }

    changeData(data) {
        this.dataSource.next(data);
    }
}
```

This is the service I am currently using to provide the current data and this part kinda works fine.

---

My component now wants to subscribe to the data and print it out for testing purposes.

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = "CodeSandbox";

    constructor(private ds: DataService) {
        this.ds.currentData.subscribe(data => {
            console.log("test");
            console.log(data); // works
            console.log(data.test); // works
            //console.log(data.test.a); // does not work
        });
    }
}
```

This gives me first an empty object (according to `new BehaviorSubject({})`) and then it continues with `data` and `data.test`.

But when I am trying to print `data.test.a` it does not work and provides an error. (just uncomment `app.component.ts:17` to reproduce)

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
```

Now I am trying to get the value of `a` but I am not able to do so.

---

### Ideas

Since it is printing the default object the code probably tries to get `defaultObject.test.a` and since it does not exist there is the error. But on the other side it works with `defaultObject.test` even though it doesnt't exist either.
*(Just saw that it returns undefined but it still does return something on `defaultObject.test)`*

So I tried to create a new default object:

```js
private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject({
    "meta": {
        "a": 99,
        "b": 99
    }
});
```

This works fine and prints:

1. `Object {a: "99", b: "99"} // default object`
2. `Object {a: "52", b: "62"} // changed object`

The obvious solution now is to just put an example of the dataset as default object right?

This kinda seems wrong as:
a) it puts this huge json file inside my js (ts) file
b) I am always sending an old object which will immediately will be replaced.

So now I am wondering how I can solve this problem without sending an example as default object.

I am open for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to use the data in a template of your component? It makes sense that it wouldn’t work, seeing as a doesn’t exist until later on.

Comment: Also it makes sense that the data.test is undefined since data is an object but test is not a method. It’s reference is the data object so it wouldn’t through a reference error, where as data.test is undefined so the method .a has no reference to apply the method to.

Comment: Behaviour Subject is used where the application may update the data locally and require other subscribers to receive those updates. This causes the obersvable to emit again when something calls .next(newdata)  I think this will not work for http sourced data, since it is only subscribed to make your code independent from the async response & it will only emit a single value, then complete.

Comment: if you want to keep up to date with the content on the remote server, then choices differ depending whether you have control of the remote end. You could put up a websocket service on it, attach to that & use the BehaviourSubject to publish the content within your application. Otherwise you'll need to long poll for changes: that is rarely ideal & if servicing the poll calls is computationally expensive then expect the service owner to be unhappy about that. You could always persaude them to publish a hash/time on change, poll for that & just collect the data if it has changed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong usage of `BehaviourSubject`. Use `Subject` instead.

You have initial value for observable equals `{}`. So you cannot display `test.a`. Your code tries display `a` from `{}` while GET is pending. To get it works, initial value and next values in observable should have same interface.

If you don't need initial value, use `Subject` instead of `BehaviourSubject`.

```
export class DataService {
  private dataSource = new Subject();
  currentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http
      .get("https://7khq9.codesandbox.io/assets/data.json")
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.changeData(data);
      });
  }

  changeData(data) {
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: So the only difference is the missing default value? Or are there any other "side effects" I should expect?

Comment: `BehaviourSubject` also holds value, you can write `dataSource.value` and get it without subscription. But it shouldn't be problem in your case, because outside of your `DataService` you expose it `asObservable` (which is correct).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I don't think there's a need to use a `BehaviorSubject` here. Instead, create a method on your service to return you data as an `Observable`:

```
getMyData(): Observable<any>
  {
    return this.http
      .get("https://7khq9.codesandbox.io/assets/data.json");
  }
```

Then you should be able to access your data as you require:

```
ds.getMyData().subscribe(data => {
      // console.log("test");
      console.log(data); // works
      console.log(data.test); // works
      console.log(data.test.a); // does not work
    });
```

This would be the best way to do this.

See your updated CodeSandBox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-fcnd1?fontsize=14).

Comment: You SandBox brings me to the default one :(
So I added the basic `Observable` into my Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-u17cx
Now when I want to push new data I have to use the `.next()`? Where exactly would I put this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem with printing this `defaultObject.test.a` is that you are going into another level of an object that is already undefined. Since defaultObject.test is undefined, you can not find 'a' of undefined. In such cases, you would need to check if 'a' actually is a property of defaultObject.test or atleast if defaultObject.test is not undefined.

The defaultObject.test prints undefined because you are not breaking any rule. You are not trying to find a property in undefined object. DefaultObject is defined. The only issue is that it does not have test property and hence it prints undefined.

If you could help me in explaining what you plan to achieve with this, I can help you further. As of now, the solution would be to put it in if block and print the value only if defaultObject is defined and you can find the property 'a' on it.

Comment: The goal here is to fetch the data from a central service. The data will be used to update interface elements (dashboard). This is why I am trying to make them get the latest data. (API is written in real time)
@Edit Thank your for explaining the problem with the different levels and errors.

Comment: You are welcome Ironlors. I see you have already found and accepted your answer. I am glad if I could be of any help. Please upvote the answer if you think it was valuable in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Just add filter operator to pipe, and set `null` as initial value for subject

```
     this.ds.currentData
        .pipe(
            filter(data => data)
        )
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("test");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.test);
            console.log(data.test.a);
        });
```

or if you don't want to refetch data, you can map http call to a `subject` inside of pipe

```
currentData$ = this.http.get('url').pipe(
   shareReplay(1) // cache your data with ReplaySubject
);
```

Comment: more info about caching and reactive programming in Angular: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-RTxeyLbsk&feature=youtu.be&t=29926